# sweetalert2: How to have loader animation while redirecting

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Using [sweetalert2@8](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) for modal dialogs.

Target is to redirect to a URL when user clicks OK in the dialog. Then while the redirect takes place the sweet_alert must remain open as long as possible, while it shows the loading animation.

Tried the following:

```
swal.fire({
  title: "my title",
  type: "warning",
  html: "my body text",
  showCancelButton: true,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
}).then((result) => {
  if(result.value)
  {
      window.location.href = "/target_location/"
  }
})
```

Results: The redirect works, but the dialog disappears immediately when the OK button is pressed.

How can we keep it visible and show the loader animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parameters will help with this case: `showLoaderOnConfirm` and `preConfirm`.

From [official docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/):

> **showLoaderOnConfirm**
>
> Set to true to disable buttons and show that something is loading. Use it in combination with the preConfirm parameter.
>
> **preConfirm**
>
> Function to execute before confirm, may be async (Promise-returning) or sync

Since you want the "infinite" loader which will never stop (browser reload will update the page), you need to return the never-resolving promise in `preConfirm()`:

```js
Swal.fire({
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: function (value) {
    location.assign('https://google.com')
    return new Promise( resolve => {} ) // never-resolving promise
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```